# How to enable DImension Control Gutenberg?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/dimension-control/
Docs says that `DimensionControl` is used by wp.blockEditor. But I haven't `DimensionControl` in wp.blockEditor or wp.components or wp.element. Is this Component enabled by default or is needed to be enabled manually?[image]

Comment: Did you actually try to import it from the @wordpress/block-editor and use the component as in the documentation? Do you see any errors when you do so?

Comment: "export 'DimensionControl' was not found in '@wordpress/block-editor'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension control component is now inside the @wordpress-components library or package.

// https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/components/src

You might be able to import it like this.

```
import { DimensionControl } from '@wordpress/components';
```

Or

```
import { __experimentalDimensionControl } from '@wordpress/components';
```

And apparently it is not stable yet, so you may want to wait before actually using it on production.